# Unable to set textView and custom background in gridview items

Tags: android, gridview, textview, android-imagebutton

I 'am developing an app that has a gridview with 10 imageButtons.Now i have implemented a method called SquareImageView to adjust the number of columns to 2 irrespective of the screen size.I don't know how to put the texts inside this.

My present application is this:

[image]

As you can see there are just images in the grid.I want to give a border,and some text in each of those image in the center bottom.Some thing like this

[image]

my files are:

```
package com.defcomdevs.invento16;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout; 
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private CollapsingToolbarLayout mcollapsingToolbar;
private NestedScrollView mnestedScrollView;
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
int backButtonCount = 0;
private Button button;
GridView mygrid;
private ImageButton imageButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
    coordinatorLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oppo));
    // drawerLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oppo));
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.setalarm);
    mcollapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    //mnestedScrollView= (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.rvToDoList);
    mcollapsingToolbar.setTitle("INVENTO '16");
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            callRegister();
        }
    });
    mygrid= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    mygrid.setAdapter(new MizAdapter(this));
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void callRegister() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registration.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    if (backButtonCount >= 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press the back button once again to close the application.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        backButtonCount++;
    }

}
   /* public void setalarm(View view){
    if(view.getId()==R.id.setalarm){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,AlarmActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}*/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.about_college) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.cse) {

    } else if (id == R.id.it) {

    } else if (id == R.id.ece) {

    } else if (id == R.id.mech) {

    } else if (id == R.id.Coding) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Coding.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.Hacking) {

    } else if (id == R.id.printing) {

    } else if (id == R.id.Big) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nand) {

    } else if (id == R.id.cryo) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
class itemName{     //Since we have to bounr the image to the item with the name and the subtitle
                    //we keep all information inside the class and deal with the class entirely
    String Iname;
    int ImageId;
    itemName(String name,int imageId){
        Iname=name;
        ImageId=imageId;
    }
}

class MizAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<itemName> items;
    Context context;

    MizAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        items=new ArrayList<itemName>();    //initialize each item with the type itemName.
        Resources res=context.getResources();
        String[] itemnames=res.getStringArray(R.array.Items);
        int[] itempics={R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn100,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn,R.drawable.hackbttn};
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            itemName names=new itemName(itemnames[i],itempics[i]);
            items.add(names);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        ImageButton myImage;
        ViewHolder(View v){
            myImage= (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row=convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder=null;
        if (row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleitem, parent, false);
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder= (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        itemName temp=items.get(position);
        viewHolder.myImage.setImageResource(temp.ImageId);
        return row;
    }
    public void coding(View v){

    }
}
```

}
Following is to set the numbers of columns to 2 irrespective of screen size.

```
   package com.defcomdevs.invento16;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.util.AttributeSet;
  import android.widget.ImageButton;

 /**
  * Created by midhun on 23/10/15.
 */
public class SquareImageView extends ImageButton {

public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
}
}
```

My mainactivity.xml file

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="196dp"
        android:background="#3f51b5"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/index"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Now each ImageButton has a common layout xml file for it

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.defcomdevs.invento16.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:onClick="coding"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"/>
```

Also here i want to define a custom background to all these imagebuttons so that when the user clicks the button a slight transparent color(any color) comes over the image below. 
please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a separate layout for the grid view layout. So that each button would actually be a layout with a parent layout ie RelativeLayout and Inside the layout you have two child views. One the text view which has a gravity parameter to the bottom. Then the picture as the background of the parent layout.

Use this layout as the Adapters layout. It will recreate it for each item you want.

Comment: I did that,it works ie. the text view is displayed.But as i had pointed out i cannot create that transparent color effect while user clicks the button,i used a separate xml file for button.

Comment: Adding a transparency to things is simple enough. When setting a background with color let's say black for instance #000000. To make it transparent, add two more values after the hash. #00,000000 (without the comma). 00 being fully transparent! When the button click you could just have a frame layout as a child view and have that set to visible and change its color dynamically.